# c# call functions dynamically without if else

Tags: c#

Ok, So I'm felling super lazy and I was wondering if I can call a function dynamically by a function pointer or something else somehow?

Instead of writing a bunch of if else I can put all possible functions in an array and pass which index I wan't to execute.

I was thinking of some sort of linkedlist. 
eg.

```
    //mainClass
    private void initFunctionLL()
    {
        currNode.functionRef = this.funct1;
        ...
        nextNode.functionRef = this.funct2;
    }
    private void callNext(){
        currNode = currNode.Next();
        currNode.execute();
    }
    //
    //nodeClass
    public void execute()
    {
        call myFunctionRef();
    }
```

Comment: **[Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)**

Comment: **[Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your functions has the same return type and the same parameters list then you can use [`Func<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) to make a set of delegates to this functions and call it. Example for functions without parameters which don't return a value:

```
private void ExecuteManyFunctions()
{
    List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
    actions.Add(Foo);
    actions.Add(Bar);
    foreach(var func in actions)
        func();
}

private void Foo() => { // some logic here }
private void Bar() => { // some logic here }
```

Another example for functions with integer parameter returns string:

```
private void ExecuteManyFunctions()
{
    List<Func<string, int>> actions = new List<Func<string, int>>();
    actions.Add(Foo);
    actions.Add(Bar);

    var results = new List<string>();
    foreach(var func in actions)
        results.Add(func(1));
}

private string Foo(int x) => { return x.ToString(); }
private string Bar(int y) => { return "staticResult"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bunch of `Func` or `Action` delegates to a list and then call each one. If your method takes no arguments and returns nothing, then use `Action`, if it takes one argument and returns nothing then use `Action<T>` wherein `T` specifies the type of argument. If it returns something then use `Func<T>`, wherein `T` specifies the return type. In `Func<T>` the last item specifies the return type and the ones before specify the argument types. Please see links at then end of my answer for more details. There are many `Action` and `Func` delegates with variable parameters. If none of them are satisfy your needs, then look into [Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/).

For example, in example below I am declaring a list which will hold a bunch of funcs which take one `int` and return one `int`. Then I am looping through and calling each one. First one multiplies the number passed to it and return the product, while the 2nd one adds the number to itself.

```
var funcs = new List<Func<int, int>>();
funcs.Add(x => x * x);
funcs.Add(x => x + x);
funcs.Add(x => Square(x)); // Or like this

foreach (var thisFunc in funcs)
{
    thisFunc(5);
}

private static int Square(int number)
{
    return number * number;
}
```

Please see [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx).